# How would I sort/align two serparate arrays?

Tags: p5.js

I have two sets of arrays loaded in from .txt documents, one of the files has three values on every line; an ID, an x co-ordinate and a y co-ordinate, the second file only has the ID but sorted in order of when I need call the x and y.

First file looks like this

```
1 565.0 575.0
2 25.0 185.0
3 345.0 750.0
4 945.0 685.0
5 845.0 655.0
```

Second looks like this:

```
5
1
4
3
2
```

I'll try demonstrate what I've done below without using my exact code as it's for a class project:

```
let fileData = {id: [], x: [], y: []};
let data = [];

function preload() {
  tempFileName = loadStrings('address/to.txt');
  tempFileName2 = loadStrings('address/to/other.txt');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(750, 750);
  loadFile(tempFileName);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
}

function loadFile(filename) {
  probData = new Array(filename.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < probData.length; i++) {
    data[i] = splitTokens(filename[i]);
    fileData.id.push(data[i][0]);
    fileData.x.push(data[i][1]);
    fileData.y.push(data[i][2]);
  }
}
```

This has allowed me to draw dots on the screen using fileData.x and fileData.y as points in a separate function I have made, but now I need to write another function that draws lines from the x and y co-ordinates that match the ID in the second file, problem is I cannot find a way to align the two arrays, and I'd need to do this without changing the code I have already (unless there is a better way to split the data and use it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a lot of the confusion you have is to do with how you're storing the `id`, `x` and `y`. You're currently storing them all in their own arrays, it would make more sense to store them as an array of objects.

And then when you're looping through the array and drawing the dots, you can use that index to find which other dot you're supposed to line up to.

The example below should point you in the right direction. Also, here's a link [to the p5.js sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/codeheir/sketches/mUg_F6I1z) to see it running.

```js
let dots = [];
let dotsData;
let orderData;
function preload() {
  dotsData = loadStrings('./dots.txt');
  orderData = loadStrings('./orderFile.txt');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000);
  createDots(dotsData);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  fill(255, 100, 200);
  
  
  for (let i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     circle(dots[i].x, dots[i].y, 20);
     let goalDot = dots.find(e => e.id == orderData[i]);
     if (goalDot) {
       line(dots[i].x, dots[i].y, goalDot.x, goalDot.y);
     }
  }
}

function createDots(filename) {
  const probData = new Array(filename.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < probData.length; i++) {
    dotsData[i] = splitTokens(filename[i]);
    dots.push({
      id: dotsData[i][0],
      x: dotsData[i][1],
      y: dotsData[i][2]
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: This works really well, thank you. I was trying to store the data in objects but I wasn't sure how I could do it. My only problem now is I am also trying to map the x and y coordinates to fit on the canvas as some in my file extend beyond my canvas boundaries. I had it working with my last code but can't seem to make the map function work with yours, and suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, so in order to do that I would recommend looping through the `dots` array and mapping the `x` and `y` in the setup function. Give it a go, and if you get stuck I've updated the p5.js sketch I linked to do the mapping.